# Generate Rig button results in RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'thigh.L': Heel bone not found. Incorrect armature for type 'leg'

Tags: armature, rigify

I am using a standard Rigfy add-on and aligning to my character. All seems aligned correctly, but when I generate the rig, I get the error: RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'thigh.L': Heel bone not found. Incorrect armature for type 'leg'.

I have seen two other posts similar that say the bones were disconnected from their parent or accidentally deleted. This is not the case in my rig. Bones are there and they are parented, however, the default Rigify rig gives the model two Heel bones and parents them as follows: heel.02.L.001 parented to heel.02.L parented to foot.L.001 parented to foot.L

The tutorials to fix this say to either add a bone or reparent them and they specify adding a heel.L and parenting it to foot.L.

I have tried renaming the existing heel bone to heel.L and parenting it to the existing foot.L, but get the same error, so I undid those changes. Attached is a shot of the Left foot and the properties window showing the parenting. Also, what does thigh.L have to do with the error message? Is there supposed to be parenting of heel.L to thigh.L somewhere? Thanks for any help you can provide.[image: heel to foot parenting in Rigify]

Comment: Hi. Can you give us more context what you are trying to do? Why does your metarig have several extra bones? -- Rigify works with building blocks, so called [Rig Types](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/rig_types/index.html). The rig types have specific requirements, like the number of bone in a chain, connection to other bones, etc. A leg has the rig type *limb.leg* and needs a  *Thigh, Shin, Foot/Ankle, Toes* and a *Heel* bone. If you just want extra deformation bones in the animation rig try to increase the *Limb Segments (integer)* setting for the rig type.

Comment: The manual says exactly: *"Requirement: A chain of four connected bones (thigh, shin, foot, toe) with one unconnected child of the foot to be used as the heel pivot."*. so, yes, I don't think the generation will work with your extra bones.

Comment: Thank you for the questions. I do not know why it has extra bones. I installed the Rigify plug in, added a single rig and then took what was there and aligned the bones with in my model. I didn't add or remove any bones or modify the parent structures except as I outlined in my post. I then reset those to make sure I got it back to the defaults before I tried anything else. I can add the .blender file if it helps.

Comment: Here is the blender file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Mwjbaen_KDZ-EeydpQDy_ZQtcXgOh8qA?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the file. So you have a humanoid monster, and you have added *Armature > Human > Metarig*, right? That's correct, but it looks like that you have accidentally subdivided all the bones. Is that possible? For example you have *pelvis.R* (correct) but also *pelvis.R.001* (wrong extra bone). Or the hand: a normal hand has 4 palm bones + 3 bones for each finger, e.g. pinky has *f_pinky.01.L, f_pinky.02.L, f_pinky.03.L*. But your metarig has for each bone an extra bone: *f_pinky.01.L.001, f_pinky.02.L.001*, and *f_pinky.03.L.001*. Sorry, that's broken and won't work.

Comment: I don't know if there is an easy way to fix this. There is no *Unsubdivide* operation for bones. *Dissolve Bone* (key X) is close to it. I've just tested this, subdivided all bones of a human metarig, then tried to fix it. First try: I dissolved only the upper_arm.L.001. This worked. Second try: I've selected all the extra .001 bones with the menu *Select > Select Pattern ...* (searched for *\*.001*), and then dissolved them all at once (X). It did something but the result looks bad :( I'm afraid, in the worst case, you will have to start all over again.

Comment: Bummer, but I will get better and better at rigging bones each time I do it I guess! This will be round three! Now that I  know about the duplicated bones, I'll try Rigify again from scratch and see if it has the duplicates right out of the gate or if I somehow hit a key combo by accident along the way! Thank you for your eyes on this as I was really losing my mind!